# Non parsable POM

Tags: java, netbeans, pom.xml

I'm having a non parsable POM error on netbeans. Below is the error and the POM file.

```
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Tinashe\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>... @2:7)  @ C:\Users\Tinashe\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom, line 2, column 7

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

      The project zw.co.endlini:endlini:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Tinashe\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EndliniGroup\endlini\pom.xml) has 1 error
        Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Tinashe\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>... @2:7)  @ C:\Users\Tinashe\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom, line 2, column 7 -> [Help 2]
    org.apache.maven.model.io.ModelParseException: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>... @2:7) 
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:77)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:456)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:857)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:379)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:343)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>... @2:7) 
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.read(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:4629)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3ReaderEx.read(MavenXpp3ReaderEx.java:4590)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:118)
        ... 25 more
```

My POM file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>zw.co.endlini</groupId>
        <artifactId>endlini</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                <artifactId>backbone</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>underscorejs</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>backbone-localstorage</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.16</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery-ui-month-picker</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
            </dependency>




            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
                <artifactId>select2</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.7</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.21</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency> 
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId> 
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.infobip</groupId>
                <artifactId>infobip-api-java-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.5</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.5</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.25.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
                <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>        
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>          
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.0</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>       

            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>    
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
```

Comment: Expected root element "project" but found "html" => Seems very clear to me ...

Comment: I'm new to Mavin

Comment: To spell it out ... instead of a POM file, it looks like the download has given you an HTML page.  It is probably an error message of some kind.  Look at it, and see what it says.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com//questions/54639220/why-am-i-seeing-this-springboot-starter-2-1-2-pom-non-parsable-issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the pom.xml you added to your question. It's in the parent pom:

> Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Tinashe.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen \r\n... @2:7)  @ C:\Users\Tinashe.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom, line 2, column 7

**.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom**

You should look at this file. As @Dymen1 commented, this is a duplicte.